# How to set cookie after login laravel

Tags: laravel-5

how to set cookie after login laravel I want to do somethin like this

in web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    if(Auth::user()){
        Cookie::queue('test', '1231231', 333);
    }
});
```

but my code didnt work

**UPDATE**

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
if(\Auth::user()){
    Route::resource('admin/home', 'Admin\HomeController');
    Route::resource('admin/promotion', 'Admin\PromotionController');
    Cookie::queue('test', '1231231', 333);
}});
```

Comment: u can instead use events to set & remove the cookie on user login/logout https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#event-subscribers

Answer (score 0):

is because `Auth::user()` not available in the route file, unless you use a middle ware to do so,

or else you can try this way

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
if(\Auth::user()){
    Cookie::queue('test', '1231231', 333);
}});
```

Comment: can you give me some example please

Comment: try this , instead of `Auth::user()` write its as `\Auth::user()` in the same route file, if it works vote my answer